# Wireless mouse with rechargable battery

Tags: wireless, mice

I am looking for a wireless mouse with a rechargable battery in the range of ~50$. So far most of the mouses that I have seen have normal batteries as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H9862GM).

I want the mouse primarily to use it with my laptop when I travel, so sligthly smaller mouses would have preference over bulkier ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Logitech MX Everywhere 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y09IWGQ) seems a good option (when in sale). You can have 3 pc's paired (not at the same time) via bluethooth or use a dongle. It tracks at lot of different surfaces with a decent battery life.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting this mouse in a sale and it is exactly what I was looking for. I am pretty happy with it so far.